# Characters turn into unicode in gnome terminal with lldb

Tags: terminal, unicode, gnome-terminal, llvm

I installed a fresh copy of lldb on my machine. Anything typed after lldb makes its first output (in this case being `error: empty command`) turns into unicode literals. These unicode literals are recognised by lldb as empty commands.
[image: lldb]
This does not happen with gdb or python:
[image: gdb]

Comment: Having same problem, not sure why.. :(

Comment: Are you guys on ArchLinux? I, among others, have this bug in the most recent update to `lldb 3.8.0` see [the report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/49974?project=0)

Comment: After following comments from [Arch bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/49974?project=0), I reported this in [lldb bug tracking](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=28898)
(Sorry, not enough rep for a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that this is a bug and is fixed in `lldb 3.9.0`.[image]